# include a static javascript on vue-cli 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue-cli-3 project, but i'd like to add a static javascript file, but I don't know how import this file.

the traditional way is:

```
<script src="js/myfile.js"></scrip>
```

Comment: Please describe in greater detail what you have tried and what the outcome was.

Comment: try in public/index.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place your file (myfile.js) inside your src directory, for example in assets. In your src/App.vue file add in the script portion:

```
import './assets/myfile.js';
```

Note that you *can* technically put your file in public and reference it from your index.html like you usually do. It will work. But it's not the recommended approach.